# Decode the view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to decode the view in `asp.net` MVC View? It appeared error when I code it like below:

```
<%= System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewData["content"]) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) method accepts a string, rather than [`ViewData["content"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary.item.aspx)] is object. You should use the .ToString() method or type convertion:

```
<%= System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewData["content"].ToString()) %>
<%= System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((string)ViewData["content"]) %>
```